# How To add new objects in core data relationship attributes of existing entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

This Is what I am doing

I had created an entity called MoviesPlayList, which encloses of this
[here movieList is my relationship attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq2ME.png)

[this is my another entity which is in relationship with first entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSsK1.png)

I need to add new data to existing relationship attribute.

this is my code

```
NSManagedObject *updateDevice = [self.playlistDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MoviesInsidePlaylist" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

       NSManagedObject *insideMoviesManagedObject = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];


        //Featch Movie Results
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedobjectcontext = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchrequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MovieDownloads"];
        self.moviesarray = [[managedobjectcontext executeFetchRequest:fetchrequest error:nil] mutableCopy];



        [insideMoviesManagedObject setValue:[[self.moviesarray objectAtIndex:self.SelectedTag]valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"mName"];
        [insideMoviesManagedObject setValue:[[self.moviesarray objectAtIndex:self.SelectedTag]valueForKey:@"path"] forKey:@"mPath"];
       [updateDevice setValue:[NSSet setWithObjects:insideMoviesManagedObject,nil] forKey:@"movieList"];

        // Save Managed Object Context
        NSError *error = nil;

        [updateDevice.managedObjectContext save:&error];
          [insideMoviesManagedObject.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        if (![updateDevice.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to save managed object context.");
            NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
        }
```